# A memory-efficient way to identify occurences of numbers in large files

Tags: python, algorithm, memory, bigdata

I have six large files and each of them has more than 1x10^8 rows (but less than 1x10^9). Each row contains a number. For the same file, the numbers are different in different rows, but the six files have common numbers. In addition, the number of rows is different for each file.

What I want to do is to generate a single CSV file containing the information about the occurrences of numbers. For example:

```
Number,File1,File2,File3,File4,File5,File6
1,True,False,True,True,False
2,False,False,False,True,True
...
```

I was doing this with Python on a 128GB RAM server. Intuitively, I tried to load all six files into memory as sets and iterate them. However, it seems that my memory is not large enough.

Can I do this job more efficiently?

My code (tested on smaller samples):

```
file1 = set()
file2 = set()
file3 = set()
file4 = set()
file5 = set()
file6 = set()

names = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6']
file_list = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6]

# Raise memory error during this iteration
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    filename = '../data/{}.txt'.format(name)
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in tqdm(file, ascii=True):
            file_list[i].add(int(line))

numbers = file1.union(file2).union(file3).union(file4).union(file5).union(file6)

with open(r'result.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('Number,File1,File2,File3,File4,File5,File6\n')

for number in tqdm(numbers):
    in_file1 = 'FALSE'
    in_file2 = 'FALSE'
    in_file3 = 'FALSE'
    in_file4 = 'FALSE'
    in_file5 = 'FALSE'
    in_file6 = 'FALSE'
    
    in_list = [in_file1, in_file2, in_file3, in_file4, in_file5, in_file6]
    
    for i in range(len(in_list)):
        if number in file_list[i]:
            in_list[i] = 'TRUE'
    
    if 'TRUE' not in in_list:
        continue
    
    with open(r'result.csv', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write('{}\n'.format(','.join([str(number)] + in_list)))
```

Comment: Why would you need to load all files at the same time? One after the other would work just the same? Post your code?

Comment: @Julien I agree that I don't have to load all the files at the same time to know the occurrence, but how can I generate the CSV file I need in that case?

Comment: Again how do you do it right now? Post your code.

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, they are not sorted. Actually, they are the combinations of two PubMed IDs, representing a citing-cited relationship between two papers (per row). The largest PMID is 31840483 but it is hard to say the range after combinations.

Comment: @Julien I have posted my code, please see if I can do this one file at a time. Many thanks!

Comment: 1st you need to have an idea of the size of data you are dealing with, how many numbers are there? Can you even have them all in memory? Do you still have a memory error if you replace your last line in your crashing loop with `numbers.add(int(line))`?

Comment: @Julien Yes, I can read all numbers from six files into one set and it takes 30GB of memory (555460036 distinct numbers). But how can I generate my desired output with this set? Can you elaborate more on this? Thanks.

Comment: How about a (default)dict with `file_dict[int(line)] |= 1 << i`

Comment: Letting`N = len(numbers)` do you have enough memory to create an array `a = np.zeros((N,6),bool)` and a reverse map (dict) from `numbers` back to `range(N)`, if so then you can simply iterate over your files one by one to populate `a` with `True` wherever applicable. Then finally reformat `a` to txt file as you please.

Comment: @Julien I think your reverse map alone will take more memory than my dict (since we have the same keys but my values are small).

Comment: the reverse map should take at most twice the memory of the set, so in your case ~60GB. `a` would be 3332760216 bytes, so you should be good, try it. Edit, actually surprisingly for reason I don't understand (not an expert in python data structures) the reverse map actually uses less memory than the set on my toy examples...

Comment: @Julien I agree, although more is more :-). Dicts and sets themselves [appear](https://tio.run/##TY4xDsIwDEX3nMJsSYWgFQMIqVfgAlWHSkmKhyaRHSEVxNlDmnTAi5/1v78d1vj07nILlJIlvwCvDLgETxFmExnfxluYGDYSgqEHNlEqoTN9viKQeWV6eGeE9QQI6IAmNxvZtdA0cFV3Abn4NGktUZVBDzjmLaxKTi65uUtWxwq6OtHu@qGH7VYN2yoQuiix2nlvQzfCecd2VH/m8mYRUvoB) to cost about equally much, and my values come for free, so my proposal should take only about as much memory as their set.

Comment: Ah yes didn't notice who I was responding to, thought it was OP... yes I agree your solution would be better, maybe more cryptic, but more efficient too :)

Comment: @KellyBundy Hi Kelly, can you explain more about your code? I have some difficulties in understanding it and interpret the results. Thanks!

Comment: It just maps your numbers to 6-bit integers, one bit for each file.

Comment: Apparently, you don't need all the lines of the file at the same time, and your error raises during reading action! Now I'm wondering why you don't change your strategy to use memory friendly read function and a more efficient search procedure with early stopping!